# Updating records in many to many relationship - single table pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

on a single table pattern on dynamodb, when you have a many to many relationship, how would you make an update
lets say a user-account table, consisting of a userId and accountId as the partition key & sort key, and a gsi of the reverse, a user can have many accounts and an account can have many users, what happens when the information on an account updates
would you go through and loop through all accounts and update each individual record?

For example, if a user updates an account information, then all users linked to that account would need the updated information now. In SQL it would be easy as the accounts would be linked via a foreign key, but in nosql, each row contains all the information about the account, so what would be the best approach to maintain consistent data for the updated account accross all users?

Comment: Please provide some more concrete examples - perhaps a relational diagram and your access patterns. That being said, Many to Many relationships is where Dynamo starts to fall apart. Many to Many are often a result of designing your data storage pattern by 'what works best for storing logically' and not 'given that I will have X piece of info, what can I access/will I need to access with it?" - access pattern first design - you may need to re-evaluate your design because many to many becomes very unweildy to do in a single access dynamo

Comment: Everywhere people are discussing about one-to-many relationships how to convert that into nosql single table design. But no one is discussing anout the many-to-many relationships and how data is duplicating while giving multiple access patterns. And now when time to update, how to update every single pleace the data is copied?